# Command line program for adding curves/levels to an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I have several JPG files (satellite images) that I need to have curves or levels (not auto!) added to them using shell scripting (cronjobs). Does anyone know of any tool for that?

Maybe GIMP?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#curves).

Comment: This looks promising!